# Django ORM query returning wrong result using Q

Tags: django

I have the following query using Django ORM:

```
fixtures = Fixture.objects.annotate(oc=Count('odds__id')).filter((Q(odds__result=4) | Q(oc__lt=10)), date__year__gte=2016).distinct()
```

Where it should retrieve all the fixtures with an odds object having result set to 4 OR where the count of odds objects is lower than 10.

When I execute this query it returns 34 fixtures objects, but when executing:

```
fixtures = Fixture.objects.annotate(oc=Count('odds__id')).filter(oc__lt=10, date__year__gte=2016).distinct()
```

It returns +30k of fixture objects.

How can I get the first query to return the same amount of objects (or at least closer to 30k objects) as the second query? And why is this OR clause not working properly?

Comment: What is the `result` field on Odds model ?

Comment: How many objects have you got if you execute this : `Fixture.objects.annotate(oc=Count('odds__id')).filter(odds__result=4, date__year__gte=2016).distinct()`

Comment: @Benbb96 Result is a ChoiceField and I have 34 objects when executing the query you mentioned

Comment: Hum maybe look on the documentation, there is something that looks similar : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-filter-clauses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe add `distinct=True` in the annotation :

```
fixtures = Fixture.objects.annotate(oc=Count('odds__id', distinct=True)).filter((Q(odds__result=4) | Q(oc__lt=10)) & Q(date__year__gte=2016)).distinct()
```

Comment: Nope, still returns the 34 fixtures instead of the +30k